# is there a vitual parameter invocation as there is for virtual method invocation in java?

Tags: java

If I have a subclass in Java and both (parent and son) for some reason must have same variable (`String department`), then If I create an instance like :

```
Parent var1 = new Son();
System.out.println(var1.department);
```

This will print what value in `Parent.department` is. But if I have a method `getDepartment()` overridden (in both class), then

```
System.out.println(var1.getDepartment());
```

This will print what return from `Son.getDepartment` is.

So, why virtual method invocation does not apply in same way to variables ?

why is necessary to do Downcast as follow, in order to take variable from Son Class instead of Parent class

```
Parent var1 = new Son();
Son varSon = (Son)var1;
System.out.println(varSon.department);
```

doing in this way now will print what value in `Son.department` is.

Comment: Is String department inherited to the sub class?

Comment: You mean why http://ideone.com/ZQrQlV does not print "son" twice?

Comment: I mean why is necessary to do Downcast for variables and not for methods